# Generate Serialized Assemblies

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, release

I am having an issue building release. I have my main OS that I am running a VM on that contains all my dev tools.
The main OS I am sharing a USB drive and have it mapped in the VM.

When I try to build I get the following error.

```
Could not load file or assembly operation is not supported
```

If I turn off Generate Serialized Assemblies it will compile.
I have checked the properties on the files and I don't have an unblock option from windows as some post suggests.
Is there any other way around this?
What are the downfalls to disabling Generate Serialized Assemblies?

This is the 1st project I have tried to build under this new setup. I do have other projects I will need to build and a few do use [Serialized].

Comment: I also have loadFromRemoteSources enabled = true in the app.config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the fix. Security related of course.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\CasPol -m -ag 1 -url file://HostName* FullTrust
```